# GitHub actions command script worked succesfully in the workflow but not in my runner

Tags: .net, github-actions

I have workflow self-hosted, it's running in a Raspberry 4 PI with Ubuntu 16. I ran an app using a script inside of my workflow, the workflow passed correctly but the script didn't execute.

This is part of my workflow yaml

```
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Restore Dependencies
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Debug

      - name: Run Tests
        run: dotnet test --no-build --configuration Debug --logger "console;verbosity=detailed"

      - run: |
          pkill -f Example && nohup dotnet Example/bin/Debug/net6/Example.dll &
```

I'm using nohup to run the script in background because if don't the thread is closed and the command doesn't work as expected. In fact, I tried first without nohup and got an error in my workflow, nevertheless after using nohup there's not errors in my workflow and it works till the end.

After using

```
ps aux | grep Example
```

couldn't not find the process running at all. Which I assume that the application didn't run despite of workflow don't say that.

Is there a better way to run the application? I'm doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If you background the last command, then the workflow ends, which probably kills any child processes of the workflow. I'm not sure I would expect `nohup` to stop this. What are you trying to accomplish by backgrounding it anyhow? Try adding a sleep at the end or don't background the command.

Comment: @sytech and how could I kill and execute the app (which is basically a deploy) through my workflow?

Comment: You could consider [making your app a `systemd` service](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6), then your workflow just has to execute the `systemctl` commands to stop/restart the app. Because the app would then be a child process of systemd (rather than your workflow), the app will keep running even after the workflow exits. Also it's a bit unusual to have your runner be on the same server that runs your app... consider approaching the problem as if the runner were on a different system altogether.